# Not contract X*X*X to pow(X,3) in sympy's `printing.ccode` method

Tags: formatting, metaprogramming, sympy

I have a sympy equation that I need to translate to CUDA.

In its default configuration, `sympy.printing.ccode` will transform the expression `x*x` into `pow(x,2)` which unfortunately, CUDA behaves a bit strangely with (e.g. pow(0.1,2) is 0 according to CUDA).

I would prefer sympy.printing.ccode to leave these kinds of expressions unaltered, or put another way, I would like it to expand any instance of pow into a simple product. E.g. `pow(x,4)` would become `x*x*x*x` -- does anyone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> from sympy.utilities.codegen import CCodePrinter
>>> print(sp.__version__)
0.7.6.1
>>> x = sp.Symbol('x')
>>> CCodePrinter().doprint(x*x*x)
'pow(x, 3)'
>>> class MyCCodePrinter(CCodePrinter):
...     def _print_Pow(self, expr):
...         if expr.exp.is_integer and expr.exp.is_number:
...             return '(' + '*'.join([self._print(expr.base)]*expr.exp) + ')'
...         else:
...             return super(MyCCodePrinter, self)._print_Pow(expr)
... 
>>> MyCCodePrinter().doprint(x*x*x)
'x*x*x'
```

Note that this was a proposed change (with a restriction on this size of the exponent) [for a while](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/7519). Then the motivation was performance of regular C code, but flags such as `-ffast-math` made to point moot. However if this is something that is useful for CUDA code we should definitely support the behaviour through a setting, feel free to open an issue for it if you think it is needed.

Comment: Thanks for this. It does the trick, but may produce errors if you have a negative exponent. For instance, `x**-3` produces `1.0/x*x*x`. I implemented a quick fix by wrapping the first returned string with parentheses. Like this: `return '('+'*'.join([self._print(expr.base)]*expr.exp)+')'`

Comment: I've added that to the answer.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53070720/790973 (using create_expand_pow_optimization)